# Finding only exact matches using Freebase api

Tags: freebase

I would like to use the Freebase Api to determine if a certain thing refers to an entity (e.g. person, tv show, ...). For instance "how i met your mother" refers to a TV show, "lana del rey" is a singer. However if something is not an entity, I would like to know that as well.

Unfortunately the Freebase search api gives me quite a few false positives for things that are not clear entities, even with the parameter exact=true and prefix=false:

For instance: https://www.googleapis.com/freebase/v1/search?query=girl&exact=true

`[
    {
      "mid": "/m/0ytdbkr",
      "name": "Naked girl",
      "notable": {
        "name": "Film character",
        "id": "/film/film_character"
      },
      "lang": "en",
      "score": 5.222793
    },
    {
      "mid": "/m/0y4k26c",
      "name": "Sexy girl",
      "notable": {
        "name": "Film character",
        "id": "/film/film_character"
      },
      "lang": "en",
      "score": 4.754522
    },
    {
      "mid": "/m/0yg73tt",
      "name": "Call girl",
      "notable": {
        "name": "Film character",
        "id": "/film/film_character"
      },
      "lang": "en",
      "score": 4.567947
    },
    {
      "mid": "/m/0w1sb51",
      "name": "Gorgeous girl",
      "notable": {
        "name": "Film character",
        "id": "/film/film_character"
      },
      "lang": "en",
      "score": 4.526981
    },
    {
      "mid": "/m/03p0tvg",
      "id": "/user/girl",
      "name": "girl",
      "lang": "en",
      "score": 4.465735
    },
    {
      "mid": "/m/05p197",
      "id": "/en/bad_girl_movies",
      "name": "Bad girl movies",
      "notable": {
        "name": "Film genre",
        "id": "/film/film_genre"
      },
      "lang": "en",
      "score": 4.464571
    },
    ....
  ]
}`

Answer (score 0):

What's an "exact" match in this context?

If you simply want an exact name & type match, you can get that using the MQLRead API instead of the Freebase Search API.  If you're looking for something different, you need to be more specific about what you seek...

Comment: Yes, I want an exact name match, but I also want scoring. Searching for "girl" using MQL, will return "girl" the myspace user. I am clearly not interested in that.

Comment: What I want is something like wikipedia: If type "girl" or "girls" in the search bar, I go directly to the wikipeida page "http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Girl".